# Why are the Windows 7 Noticiation Icons suddenly too big?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

In the notification area on Windows 7 (x64) the icons have doubled in size for no appartent reason. Is there a way to shrink them back down to normal size? The doesn't seem to be any options other than to hide or show individual icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted and it fixed the issue. I tried the other answer but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

This must have been a bug that makes something too high in the bar so that it increases in size...

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is press ctrl and windows key at the same time and scroll your mouse wheel down to change them back to the right size.

Comment: The desktop icons can do this as well if you accidentally zoom there.

Comment: Yep. This looks more to me to be a accidental ("for no appartent reason") scroll wheel incident. Happens sometimes...